# What happened to the stolen Mt. Gox Bitcoins

Tags: mtgox

Since the stolen Bitcoins are 850 thousand, so roughly 4% of all Bitcoins, they must be quite noticeable.

Is it known to which wallet addresses they went?

Did they move from those addresses since? Where they sold through an exchange?

Comment: This link is quite insightful: https://www.cyberscoop.com/bitcoin-mt-gox-chainalysis-elliptic/ and I've heard good reviews about this book: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pay-Devil-Bitcoin-Creation-Cryptocurrency-ebook/dp/B075JKY235.

Comment: I've read that article but it doesn't really say any specifics about what happened with the Bitcoins, just that some people know what happened.